# Google App Script - Telegram Bot - setChatPhoto

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, telegram-bot

i want a telegram bot that set a specific photo as a group image. Here you can see the bot api about that method(https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setchatphoto).

I'm using this function but it doesn't work.

```
function myFunction(){
    var chatId = SUPERGOUP_CHAT_ID
    var photo = {
      file_id: FILE_ID,
      file_size: 425707,
      file_path: 'documents/file_2.png'
    }

    var data = {
      method: "post",
      payload: {
        method: "setChatPhoto",
        chat_id: String(zone),
        photo: JSON.stringify(photo)
      }
    }
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);

  }
```

Telegram answer to the function up here:

```
 {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: photo should be uploaded as an InputFile"}
```

Searching online i found this solution but it also doesn't work.

```
 function uploadFile() {
   var group = SUPERGOUP_CHAT_ID
   var boundary = "labnol";
   var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('FILE_ID').getBlob();

   var attributes = "{\"name\":\"asd.jpg\", \"parent\":{\"id\":\"FOLDER_ID\"}}";

   var requestBody = Utilities.newBlob(
     "--"+boundary+"\r\n"
     + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attributes\"\r\n\r\n"
     + attributes+"\r\n"+"--"+boundary+"\r\n"
     + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+blob.getName()+"\"\r\n"
   + "Content-Type: " + blob.getContentType()+"\r\n\r\n").getBytes()
   .concat(blob.getBytes())
   .concat(Utilities.newBlob("\r\n--"+boundary+"--\r\n").getBytes());

   var options = {
     method: "post",
     contentType: "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary,
     payload: {
       method: "setChatPhoto",
       chat_id: String(group),
       photo: requestBody
     }
   };

  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token , options);

 Logger.log(request.getContentText());

 }
```

Telegram answer to the function up here:

```
Timeout: https://api.telegram.org/bot_TOKEN
```

Can you maybe find a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume your `token` is defined somewhere? TeleGram API will reject your request without it. https://core.telegram.org/bots#3-how-do-i-create-a-bot

Comment: Yes. I have a working telegram bot that does a bunch of stuff. The real problem here is that I can't upload to telegram my photo. @Chris W

Comment: Can you try logging the response and posting it? It would help figure out what is going wrong. Also where is the photo stored? on your Google Drive or already on Telegram?

Comment: I added the server responses. In the first function the file is on telegram servers and i try to import it using his file_id. In the second case the file is on my Google Drive account.